# JavaScript Canvas create square

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to draw a square with a function like following.

How can I modify following function to create a square.

```
function square() {

    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            tool.started = true;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started && checkboxSquare.checked) {
            context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started && checkboxSquare.checked) {
            tool.mousemove(ev);
            tool.started = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `rect()` method built-in?

Comment: @Feathercrown I mean drawing a square / rec with the mouse I do not know how to modify to function to accomplish this

Comment: Do you want to have the square actually put onto the canvas on mouseup?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rework:

```js
var Square;
(function(Square) {
  var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
  canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
  canvas.width = 800;
  canvas.height = 800;
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var drawing = false;
  var square = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 0,
    h: 0,
    color: getColor()
  };
  var persistentSquares = [];

  function getColor() {
    return "rgb(" +
      Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ", " +
      Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ", " +
      Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ")";
  }

  function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var pSquareIndex = 0; pSquareIndex < persistentSquares.length; pSquareIndex++) {
      var pSquare = persistentSquares[pSquareIndex];
      context.fillStyle = pSquare.color;
      context.fillRect(pSquare.x, pSquare.y, pSquare.w - pSquare.x, pSquare.h - pSquare.y);
      context.strokeRect(pSquare.x, pSquare.y, pSquare.w - pSquare.x, pSquare.h - pSquare.y);
    }
    context.strokeRect(square.x, square.y, square.w - square.x, square.h - square.y);
  }
  canvas.onmousedown = function(evt) {
    square.x = evt.offsetX;
    square.y = evt.offsetY;
    square.w = evt.offsetX;
    square.h = evt.offsetY;
    drawing = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };
  canvas.onmousemove = function(evt) {
    if (drawing) {
      square.w = evt.offsetX;
      square.h = evt.offsetY;
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
  };

  function leave(evt) {
    if (!drawing) {
      return;
    }
    square.w = evt.offsetX;
    square.h = evt.offsetY;
    drawing = false;
    persistentSquares.push(square);
    square = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: 0,
      h: 0,
      color: getColor()
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };
  canvas.onmouseup = leave;
  canvas.onmouseleave = leave;
})(Square || (Square = {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your lucky day! I was just working on something like this. If you use it for anything, be sure to credit me! ;)

Note that circle and oval are still a Work in Progress.

Link to JSFiddle that will be updated when I update the program: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Feathercrown/8uru4h44/8/)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var mx=300;
var my=300;
var currentObject = {};

document.onmousemove = function(e){
    mx=e.pageX-8;
    my=e.pageY-8;
}
document.onmousedown = function(e){
    var obj = document.getElementById("objSel").value;
    currentObject.type=obj;
    if(obj=="Rectangle"||currentObject.type=="Square"){
     currentObject.x=e.pageX-8;
     currentObject.y=e.pageY-8;
    }
}
document.onmouseup = function(e){
    mx=e.pageX-8;
    my=e.pageY-8;
    objects.push(complete(currentObject));
    currentObject={};
}

var objects = [];

function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mx-5,my);
    ctx.lineTo(mx+5,my);
    ctx.moveTo(mx,my-5);
    ctx.lineTo(mx,my+5);
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    if(currentObject.type=="Rectangle"){
     ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(currentObject.x,currentObject.y,mx-currentObject.x,my-currentObject.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    draw(complete(currentObject));
    for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
        draw(objects[i]);
    }
}
setInterval(render,5);
render();

function complete(o){
    if(o.type=="Square"){
        var sidelength = Math.max(Math.abs(mx-o.x),Math.abs(my-o.y));
        var fix = function(input){
            if(input==0){
                return 1;
            } else {
                return input;
            }
        };
     o.length=fix(Math.sign(mx-o.x))*sidelength;
     o.height=fix(Math.sign(my-o.y))*sidelength;
    } else if(o.type=="Rectangle"){
     o.length=mx-o.x;
     o.height=my-o.y;
    }
    return o;
}

function draw(o){
    if(o.type=="Square"||o.type=="Rectangle"){
     ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(o.x,o.y,o.length,o.height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid black;" width="500" height="500">Please use a browser that supports the canvas element and make sure your Javascript is working properly.</canvas>
<br>
<span id="testing"></span>
<select id="objSel">
    <option>Square</option>
    <option>Rectangle</option>
    <option>Circle</option>
    <option>Oval</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks I will check this out :)

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer was helpful to you, be sure to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: You should use `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `setInterval` especially at 5ms as you will only see 1 or part of one out of every 2 or 3 renders depending on display refresh rate

Comment: @Blindman67 Point considered. I might add it in later.